# Getting an empty query when querying documents on Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to build a Firebase Function that checks the "Friends" collection for "scheduled, ==, true" and then create a new document in the "Filings" collection with the "fname".

My Firetore is set up as follows:

```
 Users (collection)
    User IDs (documents)
         |
         |
  Friends (collection)
     Friends (documents with auto IDs)
     [fname, scheduled: true/false]
            |
            |
         Filings (collection)
            Filings (documents with auto IDs)
```

[image: Here is a screenshot:]

Whenever I run the following function, I get an error stating that the doc is empty, even though it is not. I don't understand why that is. Hoping to get your advice

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async context => {
    const task = await (db.collection('friends').where('scheduled', '==', true).get());

    if (task.empty) {

        console.log('doc is empty');
        return;
    }

    task.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.id, '==>' , element.data());
    
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `friends` collection is nested under a `users` document. Your `db.collection('friends')` code only accesses the top-level `friends` collection, which likely doesn't exist.

To access all `friends` collections, use:

```
db.collectionGroup('friends').where('scheduled', '==', true).get()
```